# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' Tried everything found from the Internet

Tags: python, pandas, pip, conda

Once I run the code in a py file, e.g.

`a.py` and inside it:
import pandas as pd
......other code

then run it with:

```
gunicorn main:app -b 0.0.0.0:7000
```

It crashed with this error:

```
$ gunicorn main:app -b 0.0.0.0:7000
[2021-06-29 23:51:28 +0000] [302255] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.2
[2021-06-29 23:51:28 +0000] [302255] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7000 (302255)
[2021-06-29 23:51:28 +0000] [302255] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-06-29 23:51:28 +0000] [302260] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 302260
[2021-06-29 23:51:28 +0000] [302260] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/api/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from answor import Answor
  File "/home/ubuntu/api/answor.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
[2021-06-29 23:51:28 +0000] [302260] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 302260)
[2021-06-29 23:51:28 +0000] [302255] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-06-29 23:51:28 +0000] [302255] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

But if I run the import code from terminal, it works:

```
~$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
>>> a
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
>>>
```

Installed pandas with conda

```
conda install -n base pandas
```

then:

```
conda list
```

I can see the pandas

```
pandas                    1.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
```

the error is still there.

So uninstalled and reinstalled(just the pandas):

```
conda uninstall --force pandas
conda install pandas
```

My current conda env is `(base)` and this is intended.

Then I ran this:

```
$ pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.2.5
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy
Required-by: fastai
```

and I can find there are 2 pandas related folder

`pandas` and `pandas-1.2.5.dist-info`

So I checked where is the python

```
~$ which python
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/python
```

Also ran:

`pip freeze` and `pip3 freeze`

I can `pandas` everywhere.

I also run

```
pip install pandas
pip3 install pandas
```

Issue is still there.

I don't want to uninstall everything as there is another application running.

Any idea?

---

**Update 1**

To see where the `gunicorn` is installed:

~$ which gunicorn
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn

I did notice this at the 1st place and thus ran:

```
~$ conda install -n base gunicorn
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - fastchan/noarch::fastai==2.4=py_0
done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/ubuntu/miniconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - gunicorn


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pandas             pkgs/main/linux-64::pandas-1.2.5-py38h295c915_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

This time I found a difference which is it also installed pandas :).

After ran this install for `gunicorn` under conda, I ran

```
$ which gunicorn
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn
```

But it still shows the old path.

Then I ran the following commands:

```
$ python -m pip install pandas gunicorn
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: gunicorn in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gunicorn) (52.0.0.post20210125)
```

But unfortunately, I tried to run my app with `gunicorn` again, the issue persists.

Comment: Where is your python interpreter? Are you working on venv or something? (It is hard to say exactly because different debugging / running method can lead to using different python.exe)

Comment: Does running `gunicorn` use your Python installation? What's the output of `which python`?

Comment: hi @NickODell yes I have done that, please take a closer look to my question as it has everything about `which python`

Comment: hi @Nikita I actually have provided that info in my post. Search `which python` on this page, you should see that information.

Comment: @Franva Err, I meant to ask you to run the command `which gunicorn` and post the output of that. Apologies.

Comment: hi @NickODell good thought man. yes I did notice that as well and found the gunicorn was not installed under miniconda's directory. See what I found in the Update section

Comment: your python interpreter is in `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8`, in this path, try to find `pip` and install the required packages.

Comment: hi @Ferris I did see that, I have cd into that directory and I can confirm that the `pandas` is there. But the issue persists

Comment: have you tried to install `gunicorn` using miniconda?, that way gunicorn would use miniconda's python binary (where you can find `pandas`) instead of the one in the system.

Answer (score -1):

From your base conda environment, try:

```sh
# Install packages
python -m pip install pandas
python -m pip install gunicorn

# Run the program
python -m gunicorn main:app -b 0.0.0.0:7000
```

If that doesn't work, try creating a new conda environment like so, then run the installation steps above.

```sh
# Replace myenv with any name
conda create -n myenv python
```

Comment: tried to install these 2 with pip, but not working....